# how to access Yup internal state and update it manually

Tags: javascript, yup

i'm working on a code validation form i need to access yup state manually and update it because when i set input value manually like (input.value) yup state is not updated and notified by that new value.

this is how values are set (inputs are set in table called refs having references of all inputs 'using react and material ui')

> refs.forEach((inp, index) => (
> index != 6 ?
> inp.value = code[index] : null
> ));